# How can I retrigger this ngFor on this multiselect upon entering a search term?

Tags: angular

I've created a stackblitz that reproduces my current issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jewewq

What I have is a sort of multiselect with two different states (assigned, unassigned), and a filter bar at the top:
[screenshot of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o53bF.png)

If I click on the X next to the Assigned names, then it moves that user to the Unassigned section. And viceversa, if I click on an unassigned one, it moves the user to the assigned section.

The problem I have is when I use the search/filter input. If I put "Ricardo" in there, which is assigned by default, it correctly shows the user, but if I click the "x" in order to unassign the user, then it correctly removes it from the assign but then it doesn't show him as "Unassigned". (And viceversa: searching for an unassigned user, clicking to assign it removes the user from the unassigned list but does not adds the user to the assigned list).

My guess is I need to somehow retrigger ngFor of "unassigned" but I don't understand why my approach works when there's no search term but breaks when there's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrigger ngFor with Pipe you need to update inputs for Pipe:

```
*ngFor="let user of unassigned | searchUsers:'fullName':query; 
                        |                       |         |
                       (1)                      (2)      (3)
```

By update inputs I mean update reference to those parameter.

`fullName`(2) is a static value. So, in order to trigger Pipe you need either type anything else(update `query` parameter(3)) or update reference for `searchUsers`(1) property.

Update should happen **immutably**, but you use `Array.prototype.sort()` method which mutates origin array(sorts in-place).

```
this.unassigned = this.unassigned.sort(this.sortAlphabetically);
```

Even if you reassign origin array to sorted array it doesn't update reference to original array.

What you can try instead is to sort immutably:

```
this.unassigned = [...this.unassigned].sort(this.sortAlphabetically);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5dwruw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-assigner.component.ts)**